# Animated gif in Delphi XE 3 forms

Tags: delphi, animation, gif, delphi-xe3, timage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use Animated Gif in a delphi form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573572/how-to-use-animated-gif-in-a-delphi-form)

I recently updated my version of **Delphi 7** to **Delphi XE3**.

Using Delphi 7, I used a component to put a GIF on a TImage, delphi XE3 already has compatibility with gif's, it is not necessary to install any additional third party components.

my question is: when I attach the gif to TImate, it becomes static, shows only the first frame.

is there any command for this? like Image1.Play or something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870944/animated-gif-in-firemonkey

Comment: @slotomo That question is about FMX but this is no doubt a VCL question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are right! When I saw delphi-xe3 tag I had automatically associated with firemonkey.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the animation started do like this:

```
(Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage).AnimateLoop := glEnabled;
(Image1.Picture.Graphic as TGIFImage).Animate := true;
```

To control the animation speed, set the `AnimationSpeed` property between 0..1000, default value is 100.

See also @DavidHeffernan's answer, [How to use Animated Gif in a delphi form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9573900/576719)

Comment: Thx, you answer was more complete.

Comment: If anyone was wondering how to do this in C++ builder:

`((TGIFImage*)(Image1->Picture->Graphic))->Animate = true`

Comment: TImage in Xe6 does not have Picture.Graphic and tGifImage
How can do it in XE6?

Comment: @Amin, XE6 VCL TImage definitely has Picture.Graphic properties. Did you include Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg?  Or are you using FireMonkey?

Comment: @LURD Yes I am using FireMonkey.

Comment: @Amin, then I suggest you read [Animated GIF in Firemonkey](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13418987/576719) where a possibility is to use [TBitmapListAnimation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Ani.TBitmapListAnimation).

Answer (score 8):

Required unit:

```
uses Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg
```

Code to animate:

```
TGIFImage(Image1.Picture.Graphic).Animate := True;
```