# Play gif picture animation inside firemonkey application

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

How I can play gif picture animation using Firemonkey that will be used in Android and iOS app ?

I am using Delphi XE 8.

Note: I saw this question [Animated GIF in Firemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870944/animated-gif-in-firemonkey)
but I dont have the animation as sprites only as a single gif file.

Comment: Did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158186/animated-gif-in-delphi-xe-3-forms and http://galfar.vevb.net/imaging/smf/index.php?topic=814.0

Comment: yes I used to do this in vcl applications but it does not work with firemonkey

Comment: @Hans -- how could i get more information about your company?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870944/animated-gif-in-firemonkey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use third-party library. One of the best options is the control TSkAnimatedImage of the library Skia4Delphi: https://github.com/skia4delphi/skia4delphi

Answer (score 0):

Due to how Firemonkey works with images and bitmaps, `TGIFImage` doesn't exist anymore.

So the easiest way of doing this is by using a `TWebBrowser` component and then loading your `.gif` file into that component

For Firemonkey Apps you can set the deployment of files for each different platform, but in the case of a Windows Firemonkey App you can add your `.gif` files to your project and then set the URL to the local file (or you can set it to a remote URL if you want to use a gif that you don't have)

And to get your gif in the browser for Win simply set the gif as the URL

```
WebBrowser1.URL := 'file://'+ ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+'images\somegif.gif';
WebBrowser1.Navigate;
```