# How to use animated gif in Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, animated-gif, delphi-10.2-tokyo

How can I use animated GIF in Firemonky. I can load the gif using Timage but it's not animating. I am using Delphi 10.2 tokyo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Play gif picture animation inside firemonkey application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257998/play-gif-picture-animation-inside-firemonkey-application)

Answer (score 5):

Use TBitmapListAnimation.

1. Place  TImage on Form
2. Place TBitmapListAnimation into TImage like on screenshot: [image]
3. Set properties in TBitmapListAnimation
   AnimationBitmap - [image]
   You can use online convertorsm that split gif into frames.

http://ezgif.com/split

http://www.photojoiner.net/merge-photos/editor/#

Set another properties:
AnimationCount = 8, AnimationRowCount = 1,
Enabled = True
Duration in seconds,
PropertyName = Bitmap.

Please vote if you like this answer.

P.s. How to create an animation bitmap from a list of images to use in TBitmapListAnimation?
[Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CFymsKtZ6fniBDZgQg5nXHeqo-ProTf3/edit) this app, [here](https://fire-monkey.ru/topic/5154-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-animation-bitmap-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA-how-to-create-an-animation-bitmap-from-a-list-of-images-to-use-in-tbitmaplistanimation/) is also a topic.

Comment: thanks for replying. But questions is how to use animated GIF image not how to make image animations. like in vcl where we can use an animated GIF image and animate it by simply by using this method := (Image1.Picture.Graphic as tGifImage).animate:=True;

Comment: Standard FMX components do not support animated GIF.

Comment: No external plugin ? I tried but can't use vcl GIF image units if that can happen can we use GIF in firemonkey then ?

Comment: How can such basic functionality not be integrated in such an advanced IDE / program... I can't undestand this.

Comment: This solution is a great way to animate a GIF by the way, if you can wrap your head around the clumsy freeware tools (photojoiner in particular, you can only join 8 pictures).

If you are somewhat handy in Photoshop, it will help you a lot to join the pictures.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe a bit late, but found a simple solution on this page : 
      http://www.raysoftware.cn/?p=559
  Download the file http://www.raysoftware.cn/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/FMXGif.rar, uncompress, and take the file FMX.GifUtils out, and put in your the directory of your application

Put a image component on your form with name Image1

Put the file FMX.GifUtils in your use on top

Declare in your form  in private :

```
FGifPlayer: TGifPlayer;
```

in the create of your form:

```
 FGifPlayer := TGifPlayer.Create(Self);
 FGifPlayer.Image := Image1;
 FGifPlayer.LoadFromFile('youfilename.gif');
 FGifPlayer.Play;
```

That's it;

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one solution.
Unit from previous answer http://www.raysoftware.cn, but **with fixed bugs**

```
unit FMX.GifUtils﻿;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Objects, FMX.Graphics, System.Generics.Collections;

const
  alphaTransparent = $00;
  GifSignature: array [0 .. 2] of Byte = ($47, $49, $46); // GIF
  VerSignature87a: array [0 .. 2] of Byte = ($38, $37, $61); // 87a
  VerSignature89a: array [0 .. 2] of Byte = ($38, $39, $61); // 89a

  GIF_DISPOSAL_UNSPECIFIED = 0;
  GIF_DISPO﻿SAL_LEAVE = 1;
  GIF_DISPOSAL_BACKGROUND = 2;
  GIF_DISPOSAL_PREVIOUS = 3;

type
  TGifVer = (verUnknow, ver87a, ver89a);

  TInternalColor = packed record
    case Integer of
      0:
        (

{$IFDEF BIGENDIAN}
          R, G, B, A: Byte;
{$ELSE}
          B, G, R, A: Byte;
{$ENDIF}
        );
      1:
        (Color: TAlphaColor;
        );
  end;

{$POINTERMATH ON}

  PInternalColor = ^TInternalColor;
{$POINTERMATH OFF}

  TGifRGB = packed record
    R: Byte;
    G: Byte;
    B: Byte;
  end;

  TGIFHeader = packed record
    Signature: array [0 .. 2] of Byte; // * Header Signature (always "GIF") */
    Version: array [0 .. 2] of Byte;   // * GIF format version("87a" or "89a") */
    // Logical Screen Descriptor
    ScreenWidth: word; // * Width of Display Screen in Pixels */
    ScreenHeight: word; // * Height of Display Screen in Pixels */
    Packedbit: Byte; // * Screen and Color Map Information */
    BackgroundColor: Byte; // * Background Color Index */
    AspectRatio: Byte; // * Pixel Aspect Ratio */
  end;

  TGifImageDescriptor = packed record
    Left: word; // * X position of image on the display */
    Top: word; // * Y position of image on the display */
    Width: word; // * Width of the image in pixels */
    Height: word; // * Height of the image in pixels */
    Packedbit: Byte; // * Image and Color Table Data Information */
  end;

  TGifGraphicsControlExtension = packed record
    BlockSize: Byte;  // * Size of remaining fields (always 04h) */
    Packedbit: Byte; // * Method of graphics disposal to use */
    DelayTime: word; // * Hundredths of seconds to wait */
    ColorIndex: Byte; // * Transparent Color Index */
    Terminator: Byte; // * Block Terminator (always 0) */
  end;

  TGifReader = class;

  TPalette = TArray<TInternalColor>;

  TGifFrameItem = class;

  TGifFrameList = TObjectList<TGifFrameItem>;
  { TGifReader }

  TGifReader = class(TObject)
  protected
    FHeader: TGIFHeader;
    FPalette: TPalette;
    FScreenWidth: Integer;
    FScreenHeight: Integer;
    FInterlace: Boolean;
    FBitsPerPixel: Byte;
    FBackgroundColorIndex: Byte;
    FResolution: Byte;
    FGifVer: TGifVer;

  public
    function Read(Stream: TStream; var AFrameList: TGifFrameList): Boolean;
      overload; virtual;
    function Read(FileName: string; var AFrameList: TGifFrameList): Boolean;
      overload; virtual;
    function ReadRes(Instance: THandle; ResName: string; ResType: PChar;
      var AFrameList: TGifFrameList): Boolean; overload; virtual;
    function ReadRes(Instance: THandle; ResId: Integer; ResType: PChar;
      var AFrameList: TGifFrameList): Boolean; overload; virtual;

    function Check(Stream: TStream): Boolean; overload; virtual;
    function Check(FileName: string): Boolean; overload; virtual;
  public
    constructor Create; virtual;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    property Header: TGIFHeader read FHeader;
    property ScreenWidth: Integer read FScreenWidth;
    property ScreenHeight: Integer read FScreenHeight;
    property Interlace: Boolean read FInterlace;
    property BitsPerPixel: Byte read FBitsPerPixel;
    property Background: Byte read FBackgroundColorIndex;
    property Resolution: Byte read FResolution;
    property GifVer: TGifVer read FGifVer;
  end;

  TGifFrameItem = class
    FDisposalMethod: Integer;
    FPos: TPoint;
    FTime: Integer;
    FDisbitmap: TBitmap;
    fBackColor : TalphaColor;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Bitmap : TBitmap read FDisbitmap;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Math;

function swap16(x: UInt16): UInt16; inline;
begin
  Result := ((x and $FF) shl 8) or ((x and $FF00) shr 8);
end;

function swap32(x: UInt32): UInt32; inline;
begin
  Result := ((x and $FF) shl 24) or ((x and $FF00) shl 8) or
    ((x and $FF0000) shr 8) or ((x and $FF000000) shr 24);
end;

function LEtoN(Value: word): word; overload;
begin
  Result := swap16(Value);
end;

function LEtoN(Value: Dword): Dword; overload;
begin
  Result := swap32(Value);
end;

procedure MergeBitmap(const Source, Dest: TBitmap; SrcRect: TRect;
  DestX, DestY: Integer);
var
  I, J, MoveBytes: Integer;
  SrcData, DestData: TBitmapData;
  lpColorSrc, lpColorDst: PInternalColor;
begin

  With Dest do
  begin
    if Map(TMapAccess.Write, DestData) then
      try
        if Source.Map(TMapAccess.Read, SrcData) then
          try
            if SrcRect.Left < 0 then
            begin
              Dec(DestX, SrcRect.Left);
              SrcRect.Left := 0;
            end;
            if SrcRect.Top < 0 then
            begin
              Dec(DestY, SrcRect.Top);
              SrcRect.Top := 0;
            end;
            SrcRect.Right := Min(SrcRect.Right, Source.Width);
            SrcRect.Bottom := Min(SrcRect.Bottom, Source.Height);
            if DestX < 0 then
            begin
              Dec(SrcRect.Left, DestX);
              DestX := 0;
            end;
            if DestY < 0 then
            begin
              Dec(SrcRect.Top, DestY);
              DestY := 0;
            end;
            if DestX + SrcRect.Width > Width then
              SrcRect.Width := Width - DestX;
            if DestY + SrcRect.Height > Height then
              SrcRect.Height := Height - DestY;

            if (SrcRect.Left < SrcRect.Right) and (SrcRect.Top < SrcRect.Bottom)
            then
            begin
              MoveBytes := SrcRect.Width * SrcData.BytesPerPixel;
              for I := 0 to SrcRect.Height - 1 do
              begin
                lpColorSrc := SrcData.GetPixelAddr(SrcRect.Left,
                  SrcRect.Top + I);
                lpColorDst := DestData.GetPixelAddr(DestX, DestY + I);
                for J := 0 to SrcRect.Width - 1 do
                  if lpColorSrc[J].A <> 0 then
                  begin
                    lpColorDst[J] := lpColorSrc[J];
                  end;
              end;
            end;
          finally
            Source.Unmap(SrcData);
          end;
      finally
        Unmap(DestData);
      end;
  end;

end;

{ TGifReader }

function TGifReader.Read(FileName: string;
  var AFrameList: TGifFrameList): Boolean;
var
  fs: TFileStream;
begin
  Result := False;
  fs := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    Result := Read(fs, AFrameList);
  except

  end;
  fs.DisposeOf;
end;

function TGifReader.ReadRes(Instance: THandle; ResName: string; ResType: PChar;
  var AFrameList: TGifFrameList): Boolean;
var
  res: TResourceStream;
begin
  res := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, ResName, ResType);
  Result := Read(res, AFrameList);
  res.DisposeOf;
end;

function TGifReader.ReadRes(Instance: THandle; ResId: Integer; ResType: PChar;
  var AFrameList: TGifFrameList): Boolean;
var
  res: TResourceStream;
begin
  res := TResourceStream.CreateFromID(HInstance, ResId, ResType);
  Result := Read(res, AFrameList);
  res.DisposeOf;
end;

function TGifReader.Read(Stream: TStream;
  var AFrameList: TGifFrameList): Boolean;
var
  LDescriptor: TGifImageDescriptor;
  LGraphicsCtrlExt: TGifGraphicsControlExtension;
  LIsTransparent: Boolean;
  LGraphCtrlExt: Boolean;
  LFrameWidth: Integer;
  LFrameHeight: Integer;
  LLocalPalette: TPalette;
  LScanLineBuf: TBytes;

  procedure ReadPalette(Stream: TStream; Size: Integer; var APalette: TPalette);
  Var
    RGBEntry: TGifRGB;
    I: Integer;
    c: TInternalColor;
  begin
    SetLength(APalette, Size);
    For I := 0 To Size - 1 Do
    Begin
      Stream.Read(RGBEntry, SizeOf(RGBEntry));
      With APalette[I] do
      begin
        R := RGBEntry.R or (RGBEntry.R shl 8);
        G := RGBEntry.G or (RGBEntry.G shl 8);
        B := RGBEntry.B or (RGBEntry.B shl 8);
        A := $FF;
      end;
    End;
  end;

  function ProcHeader: Boolean;
  var
    c: TInternalColor;
  begin
    Result := False;
    With FHeader do
    begin
      if (CompareMem(@Signature, @GifSignature, 3)) and
        (CompareMem(@Version, @VerSignature87a, 3)) or
        (CompareMem(@Version, @VerSignature89a, 3)) then
      begin
        FScreenWidth := FHeader.ScreenWidth;
        FScreenHeight := FHeader.ScreenHeight;

        FResolution := Packedbit and $70 shr 5 + 1;
        FBitsPerPixel := Packedbit and 7 + 1;
        FBackgroundColorIndex := BackgroundColor;
        if CompareMem(@Version, @VerSignature87a, 3) then
          FGifVer := ver87a
        else if CompareMem(@Version, @VerSignature89a, 3) then
          FGifVer := ver89a;
        Result := True;
      end
      else
        Raise Exception.Create('Unknown GIF image format');
    end;

  end;

  function ProcFrame: Boolean;
  var
    LineSize: Integer;
    LBackColorIndex: Integer;
  begin
    Result := False;
    With LDescriptor do
    begin
      LFrameWidth := Width;
      LFrameHeight := Height;
      FInterlace := ((Packedbit and $40) = $40);
    end;

    if LGraphCtrlExt then
    begin
      LIsTransparent := (LGraphicsCtrlExt.Packedbit and $01) <> 0;
      If LIsTransparent then
        LBackColorIndex := LGraphicsCtrlExt.ColorIndex;
    end
    else
    begin
      LIsTransparent := FBackgroundColorIndex <> 0;
      LBackColorIndex := FBackgroundColorIndex;
    end;
    LineSize := LFrameWidth * (LFrameHeight + 1);
    SetLength(LScanLineBuf, LineSize);

    If LIsTransparent then
    begin
      LLocalPalette[LBackColorIndex].A := alphaTransparent;
    end;

    Result := True;
  end;

  function ReadAndProcBlock(Stream: TStream): Byte;
  var
    Introducer, Labels, SkipByte: Byte;
  begin
    Stream.Read(Introducer, 1);
    if Introducer = $21 then
    begin
      Stream.Read(Labels, 1);
      Case Labels of
        $FE, $FF:
          // Comment Extension block or Application Extension block
          while True do
          begin
            Stream.Read(SkipByte, 1);
            if SkipByte = 0 then
              Break;
            Stream.Seek(Int64( SkipByte), soFromCurrent);
          end;
        $F9: // Graphics Control Extension block
          begin
            Stream.Read(LGraphicsCtrlExt, SizeOf(LGraphicsCtrlExt));
            LGraphCtrlExt := True;
          end;
        $01: // Plain Text Extension block
          begin
            Stream.Read(SkipByte, 1);
            Stream.Seek(Int64( SkipByte), soFromCurrent);
            while True do
            begin
              Stream.Read(SkipByte, 1);
              if SkipByte = 0 then
                Break;
              Stream.Seek(Int64( SkipByte), soFromCurrent);
            end;
          end;
      end;
    end;
    Result := Introducer;
  end;

  function ReadScanLine(Stream: TStream; AScanLine: PByte): Boolean;
  var
    OldPos, UnpackedSize, PackedSize: longint;
    I: Integer;
    Data, Bits, Code: Cardinal;
    SourcePtr: PByte;
    InCode: Cardinal;

    CodeSize: Cardinal;
    CodeMask: Cardinal;
    FreeCode: Cardinal;
    OldCode: Cardinal;
    Prefix: array [0 .. 4095] of Cardinal;
    Suffix, Stack: array [0 .. 4095] of Byte;
    StackPointer: PByte;
    Target: PByte;
    DataComp: TBytes;
    B, FInitialCodeSize, FirstChar: Byte;
    ClearCode, EOICode: word;
  begin
    DataComp := nil;
    try
      try
        Stream.Read(FInitialCodeSize, 1);
        OldPos := Stream.Position;
        PackedSize := 0;
        Repeat
          Stream.Read(B, 1);
          if B > 0 then
          begin
            Inc(PackedSize, B);
            Stream.Seek(Int64(B), soFromCurrent);
            CodeMask := (1 shl CodeSize) - 1;
          end;
        until B = 0;
        SetLength(DataComp, 2 * PackedSize);
        SourcePtr := @DataComp[0];
        Stream.Position := OldPos;
        Repeat
          Stream.Read(B, 1);
          if B > 0 then
          begin
            Stream.ReadBuffer(SourcePtr^, B);
            Inc(SourcePtr, B);
          end;
        until B = 0;

        SourcePtr := @DataComp[0];
        Target := AScanLine;
        CodeSize := FInitialCodeSize + 1;
        ClearCode := 1 shl FInitialCodeSize;
        EOICode := ClearCode + 1;
        FreeCode := ClearCode + 2;
        OldCode := 4096;
        CodeMask := (1 shl CodeSize) - 1;
        UnpackedSize := LFrameWidth * LFrameHeight;
        for I := 0 to ClearCode - 1 do
        begin
          Prefix[I] := 4096;
          Suffix[I] := I;
        end;
        StackPointer := @Stack;
        FirstChar := 0;
        Data := 0;
        Bits := 0;
        while (UnpackedSize > 0) and (PackedSize > 0) do
        begin
          Inc(Data, SourcePtr^ shl Bits);
          Inc(Bits, 8);
          while Bits >= CodeSize do
          begin
            Code := Data and CodeMask;
            Data := Data shr CodeSize;
            Dec(Bits, CodeSize);
            if Code = EOICode then
              Break;
            if Code = ClearCode then
            begin
              CodeSize := FInitialCodeSize + 1;
              CodeMask := (1 shl CodeSize) - 1;
              FreeCode := ClearCode + 2;
              OldCode := 4096;
              Continue;
            end;
            if Code > FreeCode then
              Break;
            if OldCode = 4096 then
            begin
              FirstChar := Suffix[Code];
              Target^ := FirstChar;
              Inc(Target);
              Dec(UnpackedSize);
              OldCode := Code;
              Continue;
            end;
            InCode := Code;
            if Code = FreeCode then
            begin
              StackPointer^ := FirstChar;
              Inc(StackPointer);
              Code := OldCode;
            end;
            while Code > ClearCode do
            begin
              StackPointer^ := Suffix[Code];
              Inc(StackPointer);
              Code := Prefix[Code];
            end;
            FirstChar := Suffix[Code];
            StackPointer^ := FirstChar;
            Inc(StackPointer);
            Prefix[FreeCode] := OldCode;
            Suffix[FreeCode] := FirstChar;
            if (FreeCode = CodeMask) and (CodeSize < 12) then
            begin
              Inc(CodeSize);
              CodeMask := (1 shl CodeSize) - 1;
            end;
            if FreeCode < 4095 then
              Inc(FreeCode);
            OldCode := InCode;
            repeat
              Dec(StackPointer);
              Target^ := StackPointer^;
              Inc(Target);
              Dec(UnpackedSize);
            until StackPointer = @Stack;
          end;
          Inc(SourcePtr);
          Dec(PackedSize);
        end;

      finally
        DataComp := nil;
      end;
    except

    end;
    Result := True;
  end;
  function WriteScanLine(var Img: TBitmap; AScanLine: PByte): Boolean;
  Var
    Row, Col: Integer;
    Pass, Every: Byte;
    P: PByte;
    function IsMultiple(NumberA, NumberB: Integer): Boolean;
    begin
      Result := (NumberA >= NumberB) and (NumberB > 0) and
        (NumberA mod NumberB = 0);
    end;

  var
    PLine: PInternalColor;
    Data: TBitmapData;
  begin
    Result := False;
    P := AScanLine;
    if Img.Map(TMapAccess.Write, Data) then
    begin
      try
        If FInterlace then
        begin
          For Pass := 1 to 4 do
          begin
            Case Pass of
              1:
                begin
                  Row := 0;
                  Every := 8;
                end;
              2:
                begin
                  Row := 4;
                  Every := 8;
                end;
              3:
                begin
                  Row := 2;
                  Every := 4;
                end;
              4:
                begin
                  Row := 1;
                  Every := 2;
                end;
            end;

            Repeat
              PLine := Data.GetScanline(Row);
              for Col := 0 to Img.Width - 1 do
              begin
                PLine[Col] := LLocalPalette[P^];
                Inc(P);
              end;
              Inc(Row, Every);
            until Row >= Img.Height;
          end;
        end
        else
        begin
          for Row := 0 to Img.Height - 1 do
          begin
            PLine := Data.GetScanline(Row);
            for Col := 0 to Img.Width - 1 do
            begin
              PLine[Col] := LLocalPalette[P^];
              Inc(P);
            end;
          end;
        end;
        Result := True;
      finally
        Img.Unmap(Data);
      end;
    end;
  end;

  procedure RenderFrame(const Index : integer; const aFrames : array of TGifFrameItem; const aDisplay : TBitmap);
  var
    I, First, Last: Integer;
  begin
    Last := Index;
    First := Max(0, Last);
    aDisplay.Clear(aFrames[Index].fBackColor);
    while First > 0 do
    begin
      if (fScreenWidth = aFrames[First].Bitmap.Width) and (fScreenHeight = aFrames[First].Bitmap.Height) then
      begin
        if (aFrames[First].FDisposalMethod = GIF_DISPOSAL_BACKGROUND) and (First < Last) then
          Break;
      end;
      Dec(First);
    end;

    for I := First to Last - 1 do
    begin
      case aFrames[I].FDisposalMethod of
        GIF_DISPOSAL_UNSPECIFIED,
        GIF_DISPOSAL_LEAVE:
          begin
            // Copy previous raw frame  onto screen
            MergeBitmap(aFrames[i].Bitmap, aDisplay, aFrames[i].Bitmap.Bounds,
                        aFrames[i].FPos.X, aFrames[i].FPos.Y);
          end;
        GIF_DISPOSAL_BACKGROUND:
          if (I > First) then
          begin
            // Restore background color
            aDisplay.ClearRect(TRectF.Create(aFrames[i].FPos.X, aFrames[i].FPos.Y,
                        aFrames[i].FPos.X + aFrames[i].Bitmap.Width,
                        aFrames[i].FPos.Y + aFrames[i].Bitmap.Height),
                        aFrames[i].fBackColor);
          end;
        GIF_DISPOSAL_PREVIOUS: ; // Do nothing - previous state is already on screen
      end;
    end;
    MergeBitmap(aFrames[Index].Bitmap, aDisplay, aFrames[Index].Bitmap.Bounds, aFrames[Index].FPos.X, aFrames[Index].FPos.Y);
  end;

var
  Introducer: Byte;
  ColorTableSize: Integer;
  tmp: TBitmap;
  LFrame: TGifFrameItem;
  FrameIndex: Integer;
  I: Integer;
  LBC : integer;
  LFrames : array of TGifFrameItem;
  rendered : array of TBitmap;
begin
  Result := False;
  if not Check(Stream) then
    Exit;
  AFrameList.Clear;
  FGifVer := verUnknow;
  FPalette := nil;
  LScanLineBuf := nil;
  try

    Stream.Position := 0;
    Stream.Read(FHeader, SizeOf(FHeader));

{$IFDEF BIGENDIAN}
    with FHeader do
    begin
      ScreenWidth := LEtoN(ScreenWidth);
      ScreenHeight := LEtoN(ScreenHeight);
    end;
{$ENDIF}
    if (FHeader.Packedbit and $80) = $80 then
    begin
      ColorTableSize := FHeader.Packedbit and 7 + 1;
      ReadPalette(Stream, 1 shl ColorTableSize, FPalette);
    end;
    if not ProcHeader then
      Exit;

    FrameIndex := 0;
    SetLength(LFrames, 0);
    while True do
    begin
      LLocalPalette := nil;
      Repeat
        Introducer := ReadAndProcBlock(Stream);
      until (Introducer in [$2C, $3B]);
      if Introducer = $3B then
        Break;

      Stream.Read(LDescriptor, SizeOf(LDescriptor));
{$IFDEF BIGENDIAN}
      with FDescriptor do
      begin
        Left := LEtoN(Left);
        Top := LEtoN(Top);
        Width := LEtoN(Width);
        Height := LEtoN(Height);
      end;
{$ENDIF}
      if (LDescriptor.Packedbit and $80) <> 0 then
      begin
        ColorTableSize := LDescriptor.Packedbit and 7 + 1;
        ReadPalette(Stream, 1 shl ColorTableSize, LLocalPalette);
      end
      else
      begin
        LLocalPalette := Copy(FPalette, 0, Length(FPalette));
      end;

      if not ProcFrame then
        Exit;
      LFrame := TGifFrameItem.Create;
      LFrame.FTime := 10 * LGraphicsCtrlExt.DelayTime;
      LFrame.FDisbitmap := TBitmap.Create(LFrameWidth, LFrameHeight);
      LFrame.FPos := Point(LDescriptor.Left, LDescriptor.Top);
      LFrame.FDisposalMethod := 7 and (LGraphicsCtrlExt.Packedbit shr 2);
      if not ReadScanLine(Stream, @LScanLineBuf[0]) then
        Exit;
      if not WriteScanLine(LFrame.FDisbitmap, @LScanLineBuf[0]) then
        Exit;
      if LGraphCtrlExt then
      begin
        LIsTransparent := (LGraphicsCtrlExt.Packedbit and $01) <> 0;
        If LIsTransparent then
          LBC := LGraphicsCtrlExt.ColorIndex
        else
          LBC := FBackgroundColorIndex;
      end
      else
        LBC := FBackgroundColorIndex;
      LFrame.fBackColor := LLocalPalette[LBC].Color;
      Inc(FrameIndex);
      SetLength(LFrames, FrameIndex);
      LFrames[FrameIndex - 1] := LFrame;
    end;
    SetLength(rendered, Length(LFrames));
    for I := 0 to Length(LFrames) - 1 do
    begin
      tmp := TBitmap.Create(FScreenWidth, FScreenHeight);
      RenderFrame(I, LFrames, tmp);
      rendered[i] := tmp;
    end;
    for I := 0 to Length(LFrames) - 1 do
    begin
      LFrames[i].Bitmap.Assign(rendered[i]);
      FreeAndNil(rendered[i]);
      AFrameList.Add(LFrames[i]);
    end;

    Result := True;
  finally
    LLocalPalette := nil;
    LScanLineBuf := nil;
    rendered := nil;
    LFrames := nil;
  end;
end;

function TGifReader.Check(Stream: TStream): Boolean;
var
  OldPos: Int64;
begin
  try
    OldPos := Stream.Position;
    Stream.Read(FHeader, SizeOf(FHeader));
    Result := (CompareMem(@FHeader.Signature, @GifSignature, 3)) and
      (CompareMem(@FHeader.Version, @VerSignature87a, 3)) or
      (CompareMem(@FHeader.Version, @VerSignature89a, 3));
    Stream.Position := OldPos;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

function TGifReader.Check(FileName: string): Boolean;
var
  fs: TFileStream;
begin
  Result := False;
  fs := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    Result := Check(fs);
  except

  end;
  fs.DisposeOf;
end;

constructor TGifReader.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;

end;

destructor TGifReader.Destroy;
begin

  inherited Destroy;
end;

{ TGifFrameItem }

destructor TGifFrameItem.Destroy;
begin
  if FDisbitmap <> nil then
  begin
    FDisbitmap.DisposeOf;
    FDisbitmap := nil;
  end;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

end.
```

Comment: what is the copyright for this code? can I post a modified version on Stack Overflow?